# Xcode Simulator Alternative

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode Simulators are painfully slow.

I'm making a universal app. I have an iPhone 5 and an iPad which I'm using to test my game on.

As screen sizes differ I want to check my app on a variety of devices, but the Xcode simulator is basically unusable.

Is there a way of using my iPad to simulate a different screen size?

In my ViewController I set up the scene like this:

```
SKScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
```

I tried using something like this instead:

```
SKScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(568,320)];
```

Was hoping this would set my scene size to iPhone5's dimensions and display it on my iPad. Kinda how an iPhone app opens on iPad (like Instagram's app).

Comment: Are you talking about build times, install times, frame rate inside the app etc? I'm surprised to hear someone say that iOS simulators are slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your app on iPad as an iPhone app, set the *Devices* value in *Deployment Info* section in target's *General* tab to *iPhone*. I assume it's *Universal* now.
[image]

Comment: Hello. Yeah it's Universal. Is it possible to select which iPhone version gets displayed? I want to test the iPhoneX ideally.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. As far as I know iPad has only one screen size as fallback to show only iPhone apps. It's iPad's property which, I believe, cannot altered from XCode.

Answer (score 0):

The major pain points regarding slow sims are either (1) boot time or (2) rendering performance.

For (1) boot time, it's gotten down to about 5s to boot warmed up (previously booted) simulators in iOS 13 beta.  First boot cold (not yet booted, needing to go through first boot) takes about 15s.

For (2) rendering performance, iOS 13 sims support Metal when running on macOS 10.15 Catalina.  SceneKit sits on top of Metal, so you should see massive improvements in perforance of your SceneKit game when running in the iOS 13 sim on Catalina.

Comment: Check out WWDC 2019 Session 418. In the last 1/3 of the talk you can see some of our demos of SceneKit apps before and after. The difference is quite striking https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/418